# Javascript: Creating a div with appendChild() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript

I have an AngularJS app and I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I've injected a third party JS-snippet that should create a div and append it to the `<body>` of my index.html file but it doesn't seem to work. The div is not created on in my app.

The JS code is the following:

```
window.onload = function(){
  console.log('Initiated cursive.js');
  /*
  * Create topbar
  */
  var topBar = document.createElement('div');
  console.log(topBar);
  topBar.style.width = '100%';
  topBar.style.height = '20px';
  topBar.style.position = 'absolute';
  topBar.style.background = '#4C5264';
  topBar.style.top = '0';
  topBar.style.left = '0';
  /*
  * Append topbar to body
  */
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(topBar);
};
```

The index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body ui-view>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `document.body.appendChild(topBar);`  ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I'd assume that in your example `body` element behaves as an Angular `view` container, hence everything appended to it will be overridden by Angular.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve.. can you please tell?

Comment: @Shreejibawa I'm trying to add a topbar to my app via a third party js script. Similar to that of intercom.io och Olark (chat widget). I think you are correct about Angular overriding the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and it's working fine. Probably you just don't see topBar div due to some other controls. To make sure that topBar is in the DOM you can set z-index to 9999 and in that case your topBar div should come visible.

```
topBar.style.zIndex = 9999;
```

Comment: Thanks! Missed that part.